# Capture Video of Test case

Tags: tfsbuild

I run UI tests using `Run Functional Tests`. 
Before this the test agent gets deployed using `Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment`.

I want to configure the test agent to record the tests and attach the Videos to the test results.

I set the `testsettings` to recored the videos as described [here in msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd286596(v=vs.120).aspx) and installed the [Expression Encoder described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd997558(v=vs.110).aspx).

I also enabled `SystemInformation.xml` which will be generated. So the `testsettings` file is not ignored.

The `testsettings` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="TFS Test Settings" id="dfa051f4-3d54-4d50-95ab-f414f1aea19e" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment enabled="false" />
  <Scripts setupScript="\\FileServer\shares\testdata\copySeeFxIni.bat" />
  <Execution>
    <Timeouts runTimeout="23400000" testTimeout="600000" />
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="LocalMachineDefaultRole">
      <DataCollectors>
        <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Screen and Voice Recorder">
        </DataCollector>
        <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/SystemInfo/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.SystemInfo.SystemInfoDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.SystemInfo, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="System Information">
        </DataCollector>
      </DataCollectors>
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="TestSettingsUIType" value="UnitTest" />
  </Properties>
</TestSettings>
```

---

The [Build Log](https://gist.github.com/LokiMidgard/5cb75a8c988e55059e979f92027f88db)

---

Not sure if it has something to do with this. I've found the VideoRecorder Datacollector under `TestAgent2017\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\`. There is also the `VSTestVideoRecorder.exe`. From the name it sugests that it is used to recorde the video. Trying to run it manually I got an Exception on the Console.

```
Unhandeld Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine.dll': 
The specified module could not be found (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

However the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine.dll` is in the same directory. And I don't understand why this exception is thrown.

I havn't seen this exception in any log (I have found).

Comment: So, what's your problem? Did you receive any error message? Where did you stuck?

Comment: The Video is not attached. I don't find an error anywhere. It is just not recorded I think. I wasn't able to find a file localy on the test machine. At first I haven't installed the Expression encoder. After I installed this, I noticed that at the start of the test the explorer gets restarted and at the end it will be killed. So something is heppening. in the ```DTAExecutionHost.exe.log``` on the build agent (not test agent) I found ```DTAExecutionHost.exe Information: 0 : Attachement name System Information and Uri datacollector://microsoft/SystemInfo/1.0``` but not for the video collector.

Comment: What is the OS you are using? Are you run the Test Agent as a process? Please reference [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rubel/2009/11/25/recording-video-of-desktop-while-testing-through-test-runner/) for the Video Recorder while testing through Test Runner. If that still not work, please share the build logs here for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Currently I use Win7 64bit. The provided link, in the documentation, to Install Window Media Encoder is no longer valid and I can't find a valid link on an offical microsoft site. I activated the UI Test checkbox in Deploy test agent, which start the test agent as a process instead of a Service. (At least I think that). I'll add the log.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT I hope this is the correct log file.

Comment: Cannot capture any useful information from the build log, according to your updated question, seems there is something wrong with 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine.dll'. Please check if you can run the test with video recorded locally in VS 2017. Also, you can have a try with VS 2015 installed only on the agent.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT thank you for your help. I have found the problem. I have accedently used the wrong OS. I have installed the N version of Windows 7. After installing the media capabilitys in windows 7 it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was that I had installed the wrong Windows version. I Used the N edition which lacks the media capabilitys. After installing the missing components video recording worked as expacted.